# using css3 to add depth to a flat image?

Tags: css

Is it possible to use css3 to add depth to a flat image or more specifically an svg graphic using the transform property? If anyone knows any good resources that would be great?

Kyle

Comment: Have you looked at [3D transforms](http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/)?

Comment: if i was to hover/click the graphic using js i would like to raise the graphic and expand it slightly, on raising the graphic you will notice a 3d aspect to it?

Comment: I think your best bet for this is to use a graphical editing program like Photoshop or Gimp and use images. CSS can add shadows and gradients, you could play with that to see if you can get a good "3d" effect.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, SVG is used only for 2D images.
But, if you can know 3D program, that is exactly 2D image only.
Just everyone who use that 3D program eg. blender 3d, 2d images look like as 3D image by 3*3 matrix angular calculation as rotating as you move the viewing point. That is, 3D images are the only fraud 2D image.

IF you look 3D view as svg file, first, you should code the javascript program and svg which is compose of the complex multilayer and object and same object of each layer is connected by programming and 3*3 matrix programming, too.

So, after you make svg image animation, challenge 3D svg image and the far 3D animation. That is very difficult but, you will succeed it.